# SQL: How to select COLUMN with max value in Redshift?

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

How can I extract maximum column of a row in Redshift table?
e.g. one of my rows is:
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
100,    56,    516,   1000,  516

I would like to see value4: 1000 as a result?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use [`greatest()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GREATEST_LEAST.html):

```
select t.*, greatest(value1, value2, value3, value4) as greatest_value
from mytable t
```

Note that `greatest()` (as well as `least()`) ignores `null` values; on the other hand, if all values are `null`, you get `null` as a result.

If you want to identify from which column the greatest value comes from, then use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*, greatest(value1, value2, value3, value4) as greatest_value,
    case greatest(value1, value2, value3, value4)
        when value1 then 'value1'
        when value2 then 'value2'
        when value3 then 'value3'
        when value4 then 'value4'
    end as greatest_column
from mytable t
```

Ties are an edge case here; you don't specify which logic you want in that event, so: the above query gets the first top tie column, as defined by the order of the branches in the `case` expression.